# Upload xml file, parse it & store the node values in MySQL database using PHP (MySQLi)

Tags: php, mysql, xml, mysqli

I've spent quite some time searching for this but I couldn't find any that works.

I uploaded xml file & I want to load it so that I can parse it & store the node values into my database. I managed to upload the file (the uploaded file was in the "uploads" folder). But I couldn't parse the uploaded xml file & extract data from the specific element tag to store them in the database.

The `$myfileLink` in the code below works when I paste the link into the browser.
`$myfileLink` in this case is "`http://localhost/aps/uploads/user.xml`"

Here's my php script:

```
    <?php

    error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

    include 'conn.php';

    $query = "INSERT INTO report (File_Name, File_Size, File_Link, File_Type, Created_Timestamp, Name, Address, Phone, Fax) 
                VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    $ds = "/";
    $storeFolder = 'uploads';


    if(!empty($_FILES)) {
        $myfileName = basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
        $myfileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];
        $myfileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
        $myfileLink = 'http://localhost/aps/uploads/' . rawurlencode($myfileName);
        $myfileDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

        $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $targetPath = dirname(__FILE__) . $ds . $storeFolder . $ds;
        $targetFile = $targetPath . $_FILES['file']['name'];
        move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $targetFile);

        $xml = simplexml_load_file($myfileLink) or die("Error: Cannot create object");

        $myname = $xml->name;
        $myaddress = $xml->address;
        $myphone = $xml->phone;
        $myfax = $xml->fax;

        $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bind_param('sisssssss', $myfileName, $myfileSize, $myfileLink, $myfileType, $myfileDate, $myname, $myaddress, $myphone, $myfax);

        if($stmt->execute()) {
            echo 'Success!';
        } else {
            die('Error: ('. $conn->errno . ') ' . $conn->error);
        }

    }

    ?>
```

Here's example of user.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<user>
    <name>Example 1</name>
    <address>Example 2</address>
    <phone>Example 3</phone>
    <fax>Example 4</fax>
</user>
```

I've also tried this code from php manual to check whether the file can load or not. But it gave me error "Failed to open file".

```
<?php
// The file test.xml contains an XML document with a root element
// and at least an element /[root]/title.

if (file_exists('http://localhost/aps/uploads/user.xml')) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('http://localhost/aps/uploads/user.xml');

    print_r($xml);
} else {
    exit('Failed to open file.');
}
?>
```

What am I doing wrong here? Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: If you have MySQL 5.5 or later you could save yourself a lot of headache and just use [`LOAD XML`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/load-xml.html)?

Comment: @eggyal thanks for the tips. I managed to do the LOAD XML but how do I join this statement with the INSERT statement to get the filename, file type stored in the same row as well? Must I do two separate statements for this?